# Add a new guitar tuning to TuxGuitar

Tags: software, alternative-tunings, tuxguitar

I want to add Open D tuning to TuxGuitar. I go to Track > Properties and then click on the wrench next to tuning. **+** adds another note to EADGBE. I want to add an entire tuning - DADGAD.

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Standard Tuning on a guitar is actually E2 A2 D3 G3 B3 E4. All the octave numbers in your diagrams should be one lower. However, certain keyboards and softwares actually set Middle C as C5 instead of the usual C4, and under this system your octaves are correctly numbered. And finally, guitar is technically a transposing instrument (by one octave), so when the guitarist plays Middle C (C4) written just under the treble staff, they actually sound the C one octave below that (C3).

Comment: So, the low E2 on a guitar is written as E3 on sheet music, and in some keyboards and programs will be called C3 as a different naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TuxGuitar doesn't have a feature to let you save a preset tuning, however you can save a `.tg` file with your tuning as a template.

So

- create a new file
- edit the tuning of your guitar track
- save it as `OPEN_D_TEMPLATE.tg` or something like that
- copy the file whenever you want to start a new song with that tuning.

Note:

In MacOS you can add your template to the menu so it's accessible from `file` > `new` > `new song` ... by adding it to `tuxguitar-1.5.6-macosx-cocoa-64.app/Contents/MacOS/share/templates/` and editing the `templates.xml` file in there to include your file.

you should be able to right click the application and click `show package contents` then navigate from there.

I'm not sure about other operating systems but i assume the workflow would be very similar? maybe.

Answer (score 5):

## Understanding standard tuning

Standard tuning is :

> E5
>
> B4
>
> G4
>
> D4
>
> A3
>
> E3

First you have to understand how note (or pitch I should say) notation work. The letter indicate the note name, the number indicates the number of the octave. Hence, `A4` is an octave higher than `A3`. As a reference, remember the standard tuning absolute notes, or at least that the lower string in standard tuning is `E3`

A weird naming quirk to remember is that it doesn't change of octave number when passing from G to A, but when passing from B to C. So `B4` is only a half-step away from `C5`

## Understanding how your tuning differs from standard tuning

Open D tuning is :

> D5
>
> A4
>
> G4
>
> D4
>
> A3
>
> D3

Notice how the 3rd, 4th and 5th string are the same. You won't need to change these.

So, in your situation, when tuning it to open D, you have to tell TuxGuitar that you want a different value for the 1st, 2nd and 6th string.

## Retuning a string in TuxGuitar

For this example, we will retune the 6th string from `E3` to `D3`, but you can actually retune to whatever note you want, even notes that wouldn't be logical on a real guitar.

In the tuning menu :

[image]

**Double click** on the last string `E` - `E3`. This prompt should appear :

[image]

Then for the `Value` dropdown select `D3`, which is the note you set your 6th string when you tune it to a open D tuning. Alternatively, you can press up two times instead of looking for your note in the long list. Pressing up to go a half-step lower is pretty weird, but, hey, that's how TuxGuitar was made.

Let the second dropdown `Label` update automatically to `D`. No need to touch that one. Press ok.

Your prompt should look like this :

[image]

## Retuning to Open D - DADGAD

Repeat the first operation for the first and second string. The values should be respectively `D5` and `A4`

Last prompt should look like this.

[image]

Press ok. Press close on the track properties window. Test if that worked well.

Here you go.

Comment: One more thing: Standard Tuning on a guitar is actually E2 A2 D3 G3 B3 E4. All the octave numbers in your (and OP's) diagrams should be one lower. However, certain keyboards and softwares actually set Middle C as C5 instead of the usual C4, and under this system your octaves are correctly numbered. And finally, guitar is technically a transposing instrument (by one octave), so when the guitarist plays Middle C (C4) written just under the treble staff, they actually sound the C one octave below that (C3).

Comment: So, the low E2 on a guitar is written as E3 on sheet music, and in some keyboards and programs will be called C3 as a different naming convention.

Comment: @021: That get's me the tuning, thanks. I see no way of saving it though. For example: I set the DADGAD then select EADGBE from the presents, the DADGAD is gone. I have to set it all again, as far as I can see. Or is there a way to save it?

Comment: Interesting addition user45266 ! Thanks
@AlLelopath No, I don't know of a way of saving it. I believe it is not possible on TuxGuitar.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

The tuxguitar fork over at https://github.com/helge17/tuxguitar has many updates including custom tunings.